# how is a chunk server different from normal server?

Tags: server, gfs

I was reading the Google Bigtable paper and stumbled upon this word chunk server used in Google File System. So I wanted to know is there any difference in chunk server and simply a server.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wikipedia article about the Google File System explains the role of the Chunk Server in detail. The short answer is, no, there's not really a difference.

Chunk Servers are/(were) just like any other servers, but simply taking on the specific role of serving fixed size chunks or blobs of data. The servers were provisioned, configured and optimized accordingly:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_File_System